# Fabricjs create objects in certain order

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am receiveing objects from server to fabricjs and initializing them by function createSvgFromUrl. The properties of objects are retrieved by server, the image is in website content folder. On my objects there if modificationDate property. I cannot, however, set properly z-index of those objects as loadSvgFromUrl in loop you can see below, is fired asynchronously for each array item, therefore not forcing order of execution canvas.bringToFront. The other problem is that, the objects are created in proper order if there is no text object in received data. As you can see this big IF, the object is created different way than text object.

**How can I create objects on canvas in order I receive them from server in array?**

```
var addFabricObjects = function(fabricObjects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fabricObjects.length; i++) {
            if (fabricObjects[i].text == null) {
                if (fabricObjects[i].src.startsWith("http")) {
                    var path = fabricObjects[i].src;
                    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(path, (function(i) {
                        return function(objects, options) {
                            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                            obj.set(
                            {
                                width: fabricObjects[i].width,
                                height: fabricObjects[i].height,
                                left: fabricObjects[i].left,
                                top: fabricObjects[i].top,
                                src: fabricObjects[i].src,
                                mapId: fabricObjects[i].mapId,
                                id: fabricObjects[i].id,
                                tmpString: fabricObjects[i].tmpString,
                                scaleX: fabricObjects[i].scaleX,
                                scaleY: fabricObjects[i].scaleY,
                                angle: fabricObjects[i].angle,
                                hasRotatingPoint: fabricObjects[i].hasRotatingPoint,
                                index: fabricObjects[i].index,
                                modificationDate: fabricObjects[i].modificationDate,
                                originX: fabricObjects[i].originX,
                                originY: fabricObjects[i].originY,
                                selectable: !$scope.isReadOnly,
                                zindex: fabricObjects[i].zindex
                        }
                            );
                            obj.src = fabricObjects[i].src;
                            obj.toObject = (function(toObject) {
                                return function() {
                                    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                                        mapId: this.mapId,
                                        tmpString: this.tmpString,
                                        id: this.id,
                                        fill: this.fill,
                                        width: this.width,
                                        height: this.height,
                                        src: fabricObjects[i].src,
                                        scaleX: this.scaleX,
                                        scaleY: this.scaleY,
                                        angle: this.angle,
                                        hasRotatingPoint: this.hasRotatingPoint,
                                        index: this.index,
                                        modificationDate: this.modificationDate,
                                        top: this.top * canvasScale,
                                        left: this.left * canvasScale,
                                        originX: this.originX,
                                        originY: this.originY,
                                        zindex: this.zindex
                                });
                                };
                            })(obj.toObject);

                            canvas.add(obj);

                        }
                    })(i));
                }
                else {
                    var path = fabricObjects[i].src;
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(path, function (oImg) {
                        oImg.toObject = (function (toObject) {
                            return function () {
                                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                                    mapId: this.mapId,
                                    tmpString: this.tmpString,
                                    id: this.id,
                                    fill: this.fill,
                                    width: this.width,
                                    height: this.height,
                                    src: this.src,
                                    scaleX: this.scaleX,
                                    scaleY: this.scaleY,
                                    hasRotatingPoint: this.hasRotatingPoint,
                                    angle: this.angle,
                                    index: this.index,
                                    modificationDate: this.modificationDate,
                                    originX: this.originX,
                                    originY: this.originY,
                                    zindex: this.zindex
                                });
                            };

                        })(oImg.toObject);

                        canvas.add(oImg);
                    }, {
                        width: fabricObjects[i].width,
                        height: fabricObjects[i].height,
                        left: fabricObjects[i].left,
                        top: fabricObjects[i].top,
                        src: fabricObjects[i].src,
                        mapId: fabricObjects[i].mapId,
                        id: fabricObjects[i].id,
                        tmpString: fabricObjects[i].tmpString,
                        scaleX: fabricObjects[i].scaleX,
                        scaleY: fabricObjects[i].scaleY,
                        angle: fabricObjects[i].angle,
                        index: fabricObjects[i].index,
                        modificationDate: fabricObjects[i].modificationDate,
                        originX: fabricObjects[i].originX,
                        originY: fabricObjects[i].originY,
                        selectable: !$scope.isReadOnly,
                        zindex: fabricObjects[i].zindex

                    });
                }
            }
            else {

                var iText1 = new fabric.IText(fabricObjects[i].text, {
                    fontFamily: fabricObjects[i].fontFamily,
                    fontStyle: fabricObjects[i].fontStyle,
                    textDecoration: fabricObjects[i].textDecoration,
                    fill: fabricObjects[i].fill,
                    fontWeight: fabricObjects[i].fontWeight,
                    mapId: fabricObjects[i].mapId,
                    id: fabricObjects[i].id,
                    scaleX: fabricObjects[i].scaleX,
                    scaleY: fabricObjects[i].scaleY,
                    angle: fabricObjects[i].angle,
                    index: fabricObjects[i].index,
                    modificationDate: fabricObjects[i].modificationDate,
                    hasRotatingPoint: fabricObjects[i].hasRotatingPoint,
                    originX: fabricObjects[i].originX,
                    originY: fabricObjects[i].originY,
                    selectable: !$scope.isReadOnly,
                    zindex: fabricObjects[i].zindex

            });
                iText1.left = fabricObjects[i].left;
                iText1.top = fabricObjects[i].top;
                iText1.toObject = (function (toObject) {
                    return function () {
                        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                            mapId: this.mapId,
                            tmpString: this.tmpString,
                            id: this.id,
                            fill: this.fill,
                            width: this.width,
                            height: this.height,
                            scaleX: this.scaleX,
                            scaleY: this.scaleY,
                            angle: this.angle,
                            flipX: this.flipX,
                            flipY: this.flipY,
                            index: this.index,
                            modificationDate: this.modificationDate,
                            hasRotatingPoint: this.hasRotatingPoint,
                            originX: this.originX,
                            originY: this.originY,
                            zindex: this.zindex
                        });
                    };
                })(iText1.toObject);
                canvas.add(iText1);
                iText1.mapId = Number($scope.mapId);
                iText1.tmpString = JSON.stringify(iText1);
            }
        }

        canvas.renderAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have a few options from this question: [Fabric.js loadSVGFromUrl not displaying multiple imported SVGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499023/fabric-js-loadsvgfromurl-not-displaying-multiple-imported-svgs)

Someone mentions there's a bug in the "`onComplete` callback within loadSVGFromURL" while someone offers up a sort of queueing system as well.